# Warning POM missing in the jar

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, warnings, pom.xml

I have created the jar through maven from some other project. The jar reside in the location repository. The jar contains the pom.xml file in META-INF/maven///pom.xml
and pom.properties.
I have also copied the pom.xml file while running the pom for that project using resource-copy 
plugin. Still I am getting the below warning , there fore during the building of war the maven not able to include all the dependent jars of the above jars in the war file. Other option is to add thoses jars as a runtime dependency in my war pom file.

[WARNING] The POM for org.artifact:runtime.ui:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: I assume you have given a dependency to a jar **but not** to a war which means define the type in dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that only goal packaging will put the artifact in a local repository. But then for each artifact I need to do the install so that it will get in the files system repository with the pom file. Copying the pom file using resource plugin will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to install the specific jar to your local repository  (for a start).

If this jar is properly packaged using maven you can issue the following command from the terminal:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

If it is custom made you need to include the required parts like

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> 
                         -DgroupId=<group-id> 
                         -DartifactId=<artifact-id> 
                         -Dversion=<version> 
                         -Dpackaging=<packaging
```

Please see the official documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Hope it helps